# Typescript ambient wildcard declarations with ts extensions and webworkers

Tags: typescript

I have anything with *.worker.ts configured to user the webworker loader in webpack. Everything works great on compilation, but typescript typings are not liking this.

On https://webpack.js.org/loaders/worker-loader/ They have a means to fix typing using ambient declarations but with a `worker!` style wildcards, which I consider too verbose. I already have images working using things like `declare module "*.gif"`. However, I suspect there is something broken with .ts extensions that doesn't let me match it.

my.worker.ts

```
// doesn't matter what's in here
```

index.tsx

```
import Worker from './my.worker';
```

worker.d.ts

```
declare module "*.worker.ts" {
  class WebpackWorker extends Worker {
    constructor();
  }

  export default WebpackWorker;
}
```

I also tried doing `declare module "*.worker"` to no avail.

*IS IT POSSIBLE TO MAKE THIS WORK?*